# What does github actions environment variable "CI" stands for?

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

I tried to find meaning of `CI` inside Github Actions documentation, but I can not find detailed explanation.

Except [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)

```
CI  Always set to true.
```

Answer (score 2):

it's the environment variable defined by convention in many CI servers like github action, Gitlab, Travis etc. Its value is always set to `true` when builds run in those servers.

Many tools check whether that variable is set to `true` and adjust their configuration and output to be suitable for CI environment. E.g. some tools are interactive by default, but if `CI=true`, it will skip user prompt and use default values/passed in arguments. Another example is `pipenv` that has special configuration when `CI=true`: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/207f2f565d2c4493bd8cdfb55a9b565aa58984fc/pipenv/environments.py#L27

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviation CI in this context stands for [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)