# How to know if Gradle tasks are running in CI (Jenkins/CircleCI/etc.)

Tags: gradle, jenkins, circleci

I want to detect if the Gradle tasks are running on local env or CI env in build.gradle.

Is there any proper way like System.getenv("some ci key")!=null can help me know the env?

Like this question ([How to detect if a Gradle build is running on TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886583/how-to-detect-if-a-gradle-build-is-running-on-teamcity)) mentioned, but it can only detect teamcity, I want to know if it can detect Jenkins or other CI.

Comment: Do you want to find out if a Gradle Daemon is active? https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status

Comment: @aSemy it is a good point, but as I checked project Jenkins file, only some of them set --no-daemon when running gradle tasks

Answer (score 1):

You want to determine whether Gradle is running on a CI machine, from within a Gradle task.

The `CI` environment variable is a [quasi-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289573/4161471) that is present on most CI machines. This can be checked in Gradle scripts:

```kotlin
providers.environmentVariable("CI").isPresent
```

`CI` might not be set on all CI environments though, so you will have to either

1. Set it manually. How to do this depends on your CI configuration.
2. Try falling back to other environment variables or system properties:

   ```kotlin
   // first check if CI is present
   providers.environmentVariable("CI")
     // else, try checking if running on TeamCity
     .orElse(providers.environmentVariable("TEAMCITY_VERSION"))
     .isPresent
   ```

Comment: Hi, I tried in gradle: "boolean isInCI = System.getenv("JENKINS_HOME") != null", which can work. and I also tried "boolean isInCI = System.getenv("CI") != null", which cannot work.